# Resuse JSON Object

Tags: java, json

I create a JSON object using the below code

```
while(true){

JSONObject checks = new JSONObject(jsonString);

}
```

How can I use this JSON object instead of creating a new object everytime .For example incase of a hashmap I can do like below

```
HashMap h =new Hashmap

while(true){
h.add("abc","pwr");
h.clear();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said you use this implementation https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java

You may iterate over its keys

```
Iterator<String> entryIter = jsonObject.keys();
 while (entryIter.hasNext()) {
  jsonObject.remove(entryIter.next());
 }
```

But, honestly I don't think it wouldd be better.

Comment: Im using compile("org.json:json:20140107").And I checked for this one,there is no method like JSON.clear()

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is plain java Object and you cannot apply the hashmap logic to clear.Because, Hashmap was made to store collection of items/objects/anything. From collection you can clear or disconnect the reference of its associated items. Not for plain objects.

For your case, you can define JSONObject instance outside the while loop and reuse the object like below.

```
JSONObject checks = null;
while(true){
   checks = new JSONObject(jsonString);
}
```

For each iteration old object will be eligible for GC[Garbage collection] and general GC algorithm taken care of memory & performance.

Comment: Not true if you are dealing with hundreds of billions of records.